# Why does this type equality check fail in SBT but succeed in my IDE?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, sbt, equality

I encountered an interesting issue while writing unit tests, a particular piece of type checking Scala code succeeding when I run the tests through my IDE (IntelliJ Idea), while failing when I run them through SBT with `sbt test`. The code in question is simply this line:

```
tag == typeTag[Unit]
```

with tag here being a `TypeTag[A]`. So the check is determining through reflection if a parametric type is a Unit, nothing more. I'm aware the equality check is flawed and I should use Scala's reflection API operators, I have already rewritten it as such and it now passes the tests through both my IDE and SBT:

```
tag.tpe =:= typeOf[Unit]
```

My question is not how to fix my problem (since I already have), but rather why the flawed check would always succeed when run through my IDE but always fail when run through SBT, what is different between these two operations that would cause this disparity?

(Some versioning info: I'm using JRE 11.0.2, Scala 2.12 and SBT 1.2.8 in my code. *Edit: As noted below it also happens on Java 8*)

Edit: My compiler settings, as per asked. Forgive the censoring, I'd rather be careful with company details.
[image]

Also the scalacOptions, compiler plugins and test flags I use in my build.sbt:

```
val scalacOpts = Seq(
  "-Ywarn-unused:implicits",
  "-Ywarn-unused:imports",
  "-Ywarn-unused:locals",
  "-Ywarn-unused:params",
  "-Ywarn-unused:patvars",
  "-Ywarn-unused:privates",
  "-Ypartial-unification",
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-language:existentials",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Yno-adapted-args",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-Xfuture"
)

addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector"     % "0.9.9")
addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy"     %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.0")

testFrameworks += new TestFramework("org.scalameter.ScalaMeterFramework")

logBuffered := false

parallelExecution in Test := false
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both `def foo[A](a: A)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]): Boolean = tag == typeTag[Unit]` and `def foo[A](a: A)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]): Boolean = tag.tpe =:= typeOf[Unit]` give me green test independently of how I run scalatest `test("foo(())") {
    assert(foo(()))
  }`, in Idea or via `sbt test`. Although I have Java 8. Try `sbt clean test`.

Comment: Does it fail if you edit test's run configuration via `Run | Edit Configurations...` and select `Use sbt shell` checkbox and `Use UI with sbt` checkbox as documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#test_scalaTest)?

Comment: @DmytroMitin I just tried running `sbt clean test` and dropping down to Java 8 both, still getting the same problem.

Comment: @MarioGalic Ticking the checkboxes you suggested causes the tests to now fail with the same problem as when I run it directly through SBT.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Worth noting that this issue happened with my coworkers as well, not just on my own system. It was reproducible between three different systems, granted all three were relatively similar MacBooks.

Comment: Are you able to edit question with `build.sbt`, and a screenshot of `Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Scala Compiler`?

Comment: @MarioGalic I've added a screenshot of my compiler settings, and parts of my build.sbt. I can't provide much more of it, unfortunately, it's a company project and I'm erring on the side of caution with details. I doubt the dependencies matter, the specified code doesn't use any of it, apart from ScalaTest.

Comment: Can you add `println(tag)` and see if there is a difference between failing and successful cases?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov `println(tag)` simply prints out `TypeTag[Unit]`, in both failing and successful cases.